# Why is my JavaScript causing HTML Validation errors?

Tags: javascript, html, validation, w3c

So, I've basically got this page, and when I run it through the W3C Validator, it's not validating. Does anyone know why?

http://jsfiddle.net/BcrW9/1/

Thank you!

Comment: JavaScript won't make your validation fail because it doesn't actually modify your HTML, just the DOM. Problem must be somewhere else...

Comment: Doesn't the validator _tell_ you where it's failing?

Comment: It's quite bizarre...I can reproduce the behavior.

Comment: @elclanrs - Javascript won't make the validation fail because validators don't run Javascript. In browsers however, JS *can* modify the HTML being parsed. That's what `document.write` does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Really just expanding on MicronXD's answer. The character immediately following the `<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js">` text but before the line break is **U+200C ZERO WIDTH NON-JOINER**. (I needed a hex editor to see this).

To an HTML5 parser, this is a normal text character, so it assumes that the `head` element has finished and the `body` element has started (remember that the end head and start body tags are both optional) so it infers these tags, creates the body element and adds the stray character to that.

Then the validator parser sees the end head tag and the start body tag and reports them as errors because the parser is already in the "In body" state.

To get rid of the stray character, just select and delete the characters between the two script lines including the `>` at the end of the first script line and the `<` at the start of the second script line, then retype the characters you need.

Comment: Could you elaborate on what characters between the two script lines? I'm not seeing anything between them, or are you talking about the actual script?

Comment: My apologies, I'm a little new to this and I'm trying to get my hands dirty. :)

Comment: You won't **see** the character because it has no width and no glyph. Just trust that it's there, and use block selection and delete of the sequence of characters I describe to ensure that you remove it. If you want, you can use a hex editor to remove it directly - I use "Hex Editor Neo" which is free - but that's much more work.

Comment: Ah, haha. Thank you. :) I'll grab Hex Editor Neo. You were right, sneaky little buggers. This was a good lesson to learn. :D

Answer (score 3):

It was your jquery include.
Possibly some sort of encoding issue. It happens occasionally when copying code (like a script block) from another site. I think OSX preserves the original encoding while windows converts clipboard text to some standard encoding. Anyways, this works. I simply copied the second script tag, pasted it, changed the src value, and removed the one you copied from some place else. http://jsfiddle.net/BcrW9/2/

PS -- Please confirm or deny your use of OSX in a comment. This happens to me in OSX all the time. Never had this problem in Windows.

Comment: Perhaps a BOM encoding issue. I work in Switzerland and we have all the possible and impossible issues with utf-8 and other charsets. Mostly browsers (and editors!!) are very forgiving and handle a lot of corner cases not visible to the end user and are only uncovered by validators - but this does not mean that this is a good thing.

Comment: So do you have any ideas on how I could go about fixing this?